# android: timestamp on sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an error :

```
12-08 12:05:20.264: E/AndroidRuntime(21782): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: details: , while compiling: SELECT _id, recipient, message, details FROM notes
```

Am i doing it all wrong? my database seems to be not working, I just want to add a timestamp to it. Anyone help me how to add a timestamp on sqlite? Here's my code on the database:

```
public class MessagesDBAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_RECIPIENT = "recipient";
    public static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String KEY_DETAILS = "details";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    private static final String TAG = "MessagesDBAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

     //Database creation sql statement

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
             "create table notes (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_RECIPIENT + " text not null, " + KEY_MESSAGE + " text not null, " + KEY_DETAILS + "text not null);";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
     * opened/created
     * 
     * @param ctx the Context within which to work
     */
    public MessagesDBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public MessagesDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public long createNote(String phoneNo, String message, String details) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_RECIPIENT, phoneNo);
        initialValues.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DETAILS, details);

        open();

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

        return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_RECIPIENT,
                KEY_MESSAGE, KEY_DETAILS }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

            mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_RECIPIENT, KEY_MESSAGE, KEY_DETAILS}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String phoneNo, String message, String details) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_RECIPIENT, phoneNo);
        args.put(KEY_MESSAGE, message);
        args.put(KEY_DETAILS, details);

        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 + KEY_DETAILS + "text not null);";
```

should be

```
 + KEY_DETAILS + " text not null);";
```

notice the space before "text". :)

Comment: you mistakenly created a "detailstext" column in your db.

Comment: update  DATABASE_VERSION to a bigger version (3?), to make sure your table is dropped and re-created :)

Comment: @Kev: That should have resolved the error message in your question.